# No line break before comment after else in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, format, alignment

I've long been a "align curly braces" person. And with wide monitors I put long comments after code. So in Eclipse I want to do format things like this:

```
if(foo)
{
  something();
}
else
{
  somethingElse();
}
```

Fine; that's easy. But then I add a comment:

```
if(foo)  //if foo is true
{
  something();
}
else  //if no foo
{
  somethingElse();
}
```

Dratted Eclipse formats it like this:

```
if(foo)  //if foo is true
{
  something();
}
else
//if no foo
{
  somethingElse();
}
```

Great. That whole wasted line. And it looks ugly. And it's not even precise, because I want to comment the `else` line.

How can I get Eclipse to format my `if`/`else` with aligned braces, but allow my comments to be on the same line as `else`?

This was tested on Eclipse 4.2.2, and I have just confirmed that it does not work in Eclipse 4.3M7, either.

I have filed a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407832) on the issue; let's see what the Eclipse developers have to say.

Comment: Thanks, but there are tons of alternatives. I could stop using aligned braces. I could use another IDE. I could switch to a programming language that uses indention instead curly braces. But you know programmers---we are a picky bunch and we have our own ways of coding. If I thought another way was better for me, I'd be doing that. But I like my coding style the way it is, and I want my tool, Eclipse, to work with me, not against me.

Comment: Thought I'd be able to find some obscure option for setting this, but I don't see it.  I would like to know this as well.  As "do away with the comments", I'm a firm believer that code is NOT documentation.  Having too many comments in code is VERY rarely a problem.   Not all comments are good, not all comments are even helpful, but the answer is to write better comments, not do away with them.  I'll join you in your search for a way to format them the way you would like to format them.

Comment: Thanks, @rcook; you said all the things I was wanting to say.

Comment: @rcook What Eclipse version are you using ? When you say Eclipse formats the code like this, you mean by using Right Click->Source->Format option ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to preferences
2. Type "format" in the searchbox
3. Select "Java->Code style->Formatter" in the tree
4. Click the "Edit..." button
5. Go to the "Comments" tab
6. Select "preserve whitespace between code and line comments"

That did it for me in Galileo.

Comment: This is the same as @joaonlima answer. rcook tried it and it did not work.

Comment: sometimes there are different routes to the same option in Eclipse, this one works for me so I described exactly how to get there.

Comment: This did not work in Eclipse 4.2.x, and I have just confirmed that it does not work in Eclipse 4.3M7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse Indigo (3.7), all I had to do was go to
Control Statements -> check "insert newline before 'else' in an 'if' statement".
(inside Properties/Java Code Style/Formatter/Edit...)

I'm using a copy of the default Eclipse built-in template.
If you're sure you haven't tampered with the built-in template, please let us know what version you're using.

Comment: This did not work in Eclipse 4.2.x, and I have just confirmed that it does not work in Eclipse 4.3M7. Besides, why would a setting for "before an 'else' statement" have anything to do with comments and newlines that occur _after_ an `else` statement. In any case, this does not work in Eclipse 4.3M7.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In Eclipse Profile there is an option on the comments tab "Preserve white space between code and line comments", you could try that and see if it works</strike>

EDIT:

I think I got it: In the formatting edit, go to the `Braces` tab and put the `Blocks` as `Same line`. Since I changed a lot here I'm not sure this is the only one needed. But it is needed.
The `Insert new line before else in an if` on the `Control Statements` is also marked.

Comment: By "doesn't work" I mean it does not do what the OP wanted.  I also tried the one saying "Enable line comment formatting", and it doesn't do it either.

Comment: This did not work in Eclipse 4.2.x, and I have just confirmed that it does not work in Eclipse 4.3M7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse Juno (3.8.1) and the default Eclipse built-in template as java code formatter. My code just looks like you want it to.

I don't even had to change the option cleberz mentioned in his answer.

Which Eclipse version and code formatter template are you using?

Comment: I was using Eclipse 4.2.2; I am now using Eclipse 4.3M7.